# can you test for a range of values in an IF statement

Tags: c#

I'd like to test a variable ("userChoice") for the numeric values 0-32 and 99

Comment: Picky, picky :) You might consider specifying, in this case, the exact base type of 'userChoice. The reader is probably going to assume 'int32. best,

Comment: oh im so sorry, please forgive me

Comment: no but seriously, my mistake. i thought it was implied

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if((userChoice >= 0 && userChoice <= 32) || userChoice == 99)
{
     // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Just to add a different kind of thinking, when I have range tests I like to use the **Contains** method of **List<T>**. In your case it may seem contrived but it would look something like:

```
        List<int> options = new List<int>(Enumerable.Range(0, 33));
        options.Add(99);
        if(options.Contains(userChoice)){
            // something interesting
        }
```

If you were operating in the simple range, it would look much cleaner:

```
        if(Enumerable.Range(0, 33).Contains(userChoice)){
            // something interesting
        }
```

What's nice about this is that is works superbly well with testing a range of strings and other types without having to write || over and over again.

Comment: +1 for originality and an explanation of a benefit in a certain circumstance; although it uses memory but I understand memory optimization isn't the point of this example.

Comment: +1, I would assume the memory footprint would be almost negligible?

Comment: +1 for ingenuity. I doubt that the memory footprint would have any effect on the application.

Comment: wouldn't `if (Enumerable.Range(0, 33).Add(99).Contains(userChoice))` work?

Comment: @RCIX: Nope, `IEnumerable<T>` doesn't contains any Add method.

Comment: @CMS: Couldn't you do this then? `if (Enumerable.Range(0, 33).ToList().Add(99).Contains(userChoice))`

Answer (score 6):

```
if((userChoice >= 0 && userChoice < 33) || userchoice  == 99) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean this?

```
if (userChoice >= 0 && userChoice <= 32 || userChoice == 99)
```